# MS GraphAPI returns an InternalServerError for /messages requests with specific filter expressions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have encountered the following `InternalServerError` from the MS GraphAPI when invoking the /messages endpoint for several users and filter expressions.

For example, the following request consistently fails:

**The request:**

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/messages?$top=100&$filter=isDraft eq false and createdDateTime ge 2017-06-09T05:11:58Z&$select=id,internetMessageId,from,sender,replyTo,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,receivedDateTime,sentDateTime,createdDateTime,hasAttachments,parentFolderId,isDraft,isRead,changeKey,conversationId,parentFolderId`

**The response:**

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Error while processing response.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b1ccb699-17da-4faf-9b8e-eba629be21e9",
            "date": "2017-07-28T21:33:09"
        }
    }
}`

It is important to note that if the timestamp in the filter expression is modified (e.g. by using a later timestamp) then the requests succeeds.
Changing the `$top` parameter from 100 to 10 also produces a valid 200 response.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the `userPrincipalName` in this post.

Is there a known issue with certain messages that may result in an internal error when retrieving messages? The `request-id` is in the response, so hopefully that could provide some clues.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in this error.

Try to downsize the header `Prefer:odata.maxpagesize=200`

or downsize the top query

It works for me.

Comment: My bad, it do not solve this problem, only approach to the corrupted mail.

Comment: Add an issue on github https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2913